# How to convert blob sent by ajax to audio file in python flask

Tags: python, html, ajax, flask

My code which get's data and sends data to flask server through ajax. How can I store audio file in server which I can play

```
        .then(stream => {
            handlerFunction(stream)
        })

    function handlerFunction(stream) {
        rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        rec.ondataavailable = e => {
            audioChunks.push(e.data);
            if (rec.state == "inactive") {
                let blob = new Blob(audioChunks, {type: 'audio/wav'});
                sendAudioToServer(blob, URL.createObjectURL(blob))
            }
        }
    }
```